# Keras freezing on first epoch (can't move to second epoch)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

i am using tensorflow2.0 keras2.3 python3.7
Keras freezing on last batch of first epoch (can't move to second epoch)
i try to reduce the number of dataset ,it still didt works.
i try to find some anwser through google and other anwsers,but they didt works
here is code

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sklearn
import pandas as pd
import os
import sys
import time
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow import keras


file_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname('__file__'))
para_num=40

def data_re(file_name):
    root=os.path.join(file_path, file_name)
    fr = open(root)
    lines = fr.readlines()
    line_nums = len(lines)
    result_mat = np.zeros((line_nums, para_num))  
    class_label = []
    for i in range(line_nums):
        line = lines[i].strip()
        item_mat = line.split(',')
        result_mat[i, :] = item_mat[0: para_num]
        class_label.append(item_mat[-1])  
    fr.close()
    return result_mat,class_label

file_train='xx.csv'
file_valid='yy.csv'
x_train,y_train=data_re(file_train)
x_valid,y_valid=data_re(file_valid)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
x_train_scaled=scaler.fit_transform(x_train)
x_valid_scaled=scaler.fit_transform(x_valid)
y_train=np.array(y_train)
y_valid=np.array(y_valid)

print(x_train_scaled.shape,y_train.shape)
print(x_valid.shape,y_valid.shape)
```

(24, 40) (24,)
(34, 40) (34,)

```
def build_model(hidden_layers=1, layer_size=40, learning_rate=3e-3):
    model = keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(layer_size, activation='relu', input_shape=x_train.shape[1:]))

    for _ in range(hidden_layers - 1):
        model.add(keras.layers.Dense(layer_size, activation='relu'))

    model.add(keras.layers.Dense(5))
    optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate)
    model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy, optimizer=optimizer)
    return model


callbacks = [keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(patience=5, min_delta=1e-20)]
sklearn_model = keras.wrappers.scikit_learn.KerasClassifier(build_model)
history = sklearn_model.fit(x_train_scaled, y_train, epochs=10, validation_data=(x_valid_scaled, y_valid),
                            callbacks=callbacks)


def plot_learning_curves(history):
    pd.DataFrame(history.history).plot(figsize=(8, 5))
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.gca().set_ylim(0, 1)
    plt.show()

from scipy.stats import  reciprocal
plot_learning_curves(history)
param_distribution={
    "hidden_layers":[1,2,3,4],
    "layer_size":np.arange(1,100),
    "learning_rate":reciprocal(1e-4,1e-2)
}

from sklearn.model_selection import  RandomizedSearchCV
random_search_cv = RandomizedSearchCV(sklearn_model, param_distribution,n_iter=10,cv=3, n_jobs=1)
random_search_cv.fit(x_train_scaled, y_train, epochs=10,validation_data=(x_valid,y_valid),verbose=1,callbacks=callbacks)
print('aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa')
```

Train on 24 samples, validate on 34 samples
Epoch 1/10

Comment: For how long does it freeze? You are passing `validation_data` so after each epoch it's performing validation which doesn't show progress.

Comment: Hours and only a few dozen data points